# Is there any reason this function call shouldn't work?

Tags: c

When executing the following, GDB says it's failing at the last line of `data()`:

> ```
> Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
> Reason: 13 at address: 0x0000000000000000
> 0x00000001000021ee in data (srvr=Cannot access memory at address 0x6567612d726572fd
>  ) at /Users/Documents/w11/cs176b/mftp/data.c:121
> ```

Do you see any reason why it would fail?

global in control.c, eventually gets `strcpy()`'d an IP address x.x.x.x

```
char passive_ip[25] = "";
```

called within control.c

```
data(passive_ip, passive_port);
```

data.c

```
void data(char* srvr, int prt) { 
    printf("In Data: connecting to %s:%i", srvr, prt);

    struct hostent *hp = gethostbyname(srvr);

    if (hp == NULL) {
        printf("gethostbyname() failed\n");
    } else {
        printf("%s = ", hp->h_name);
        unsigned int i=0;
        //  while ( hp -> h_addr_list[i] != NULL) {
        printf( "%i %s ",i, inet_ntoa( *( struct in_addr*)( hp -> h_addr_list[0])));
        //      i++;
        //  }
        printf("\n");
    }

    char hostname[15];
    strcpy(hostname, inet_ntoa( *( struct in_addr*)( hp -> h_addr_list[0])));


    int sockfd;
    int len;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int result;
    char* buffer;


    /*  Create a socket for the client.  */
    sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    /*  Name the socket, as agreed with the server.  */
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(  hostname    );
    address.sin_port = htons(prt);
    len = sizeof(address);

    /*  Now connect our socket to the server's socket.  */
    result = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, len);

    if(result == -1) {
        perror("oops (data): client3");
        exit(1);
    }

    read(sockfd, buffer, MY_BUFFER_SIZE);


} // this is line 121
```

Comment: Sounds like maybe the `data()` function busts the stack

Comment: GDB says it's failing at the last line of data: Reason: 13 at address: 0x0000000000000000
0x00000001000021ee in data (srvr=Cannot access memory at address 0x6567612d726572fd
) at /Users/brian/Documents/w11/cs176b/mftp/data.c:121... "srvr" is a parameter of the function... hmmm

Comment: One thing's for sure - the code you've posted isn't useful for diagnosing the problem: it's definitely inside data() if this fails on the first iteration.

Comment: I have revised it. check above. let me know if it's still not descriptive enough..

Comment: I'm not sure why you think "does stuff" is helpful in this context for finding out where the problem lies.

Comment: Trying to keep what I thought were unnecessary details out of the way, but if you wanna see it, here you go :)

Comment: @Brian: please post [complete, concise sample code](http://sscce.org/) that [reproduces the problem](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and a stack trace.

Comment: If `hp` is `NULL`, the code will print out a message and then try to continue anyway, likely leading to a `NULL` pointer dereference.  Could that be the issue?  Anyway, where is line 121 in your source code?

Comment: I commented line 121 -- it's the last bracket. And no, I don't think that's it,  because if I do a printf of the buffer it is successfully reading the socket.

Comment: @Brian: the sample code is neither complete nor concise. We need to be able to compile the code you've given without writing our own in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I can't really give you "concise" compilable code without posting my entire project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *first* thing I'd be doing is changing:

```
char hostname[15];
```

to:

```
char hostname[16];
```

You may well be overflowing the buffer, which would cause stack corruption. A full IPv4 address needs *16* characters: `nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn` plus a terminating `\0`. In reality, you probably shouldn't be using those calls if you're the least bit interested in handling IPv6 - I'm pretty certain they don't play well in that world. But that's a different issue.

---

The *other* problem you have (and this is almost certainly the cause of your crash) is that you do:

```
char *buffer;
:
read(sockfd, buffer, MY_BUFFER_SIZE);
```

*without* actually allocating memory for that buffer, so that `buffer` will point to some arbitrary location. Either use:

```
char buffer[MY_BUFFER_SIZE];
```

or:

```
char *buffer = malloc (MY_BUFFER_SIZE);
```

remembering to check for allocation failure and free it when no longer required.

Comment: len = 13 .. it's an IPv4, so it should fit (unless there are null terminating chars, but it doesn't look like it for what was IP XXX.XXX.XX.XX, == 13 chars). i will make it 16 to be save, though. it's a good observation.

Comment: I fear that SO is going to contribute even more to the decline in average code quality, as people come here to get their bugs found rather than doing the most rudimentary effort to find them themselves.

Comment: @Jim, I prefer the glass-half-full attitude of "code quality will increase as we educate more and more people". The chances of Brain D (and hopefully others)  making the mistake of using uninitialised pointers for storage has been at least somewhat diminished, and that's a good thing in my book.

Comment: I referred to a fear, not to an attitude. Of course SO is a valuable educational tool, but I'm alarmed by something I've observed in the short time I've been here.

Answer (score 2):

The last line of the function `data()` is the `read()`.  You are trying to read data into `buffer`; you have not allocated any storage for `buffer`, so the pointer is (luckily for you) NULL, leading to the crash.